# If Statement TroubleShooting

Tags: c++

The code I have is:

```
if(seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].question==seatingChart[compareRow][compareSeat][compareIncorrectQuestion].question&&seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].answerChoice==seatingChart[compareRow][compareSeat][compareIncorrectQuestion].answerChoice||seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].answerChoice==compareAnswerChoice)
```

The data structure I used was:

```
struct incorrect
{
unsigned int question;
unsigned int answerChoice
};
```

compareAnswerChoice returns an unsigned integer value. In fact, every single value in the parameters is an unsigned integer value, but the parameter after the final or seems to break the if statement. None of the values are negative, they are translated from characters (lowercase and uppercase) to the unsigned integers between 1 and 26 inclusive. The compilation returned no errors and the parameters in the vectors refer to their correct locations.

When I simply use:

```
if (seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].answerChoice ==
    compareAnswerChoice)
```

The following code works fine, but when I add any of the anterior parameters from the former if statement, the code inside fails to work.

I understand that I'm doing something incorrectly, but I don't know what it is exactly, and so I cannot correct myself. Could somebody tell me what's wrong about the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ operator `&&` has a higher (13) [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than opeator `||` (14). You need parentheses in your `if` statement.

@user3093536 it is easy to debug such thing using debugger. Create conditions with known values and test how `if()` statement works with operators `&&` and `||` in there. Step into the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by cleaning this up a bit so we can see what's happening:

```
unsigned int question =
    seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].question;
unsigned int answer =
    seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].answerChoice;

unsigned int compare_question =
    seatingChart[compareRow][compareSeat][compareIncorrectQuestion].question;
unsigned int compare_answer =
    seatingChart[compareRow][compareSeat][compareIncorrectQuestion].answerChoice;

if (question == compare_question && answer == compare_answer ||
    answer == compareAnswerChoice)
```

The logical AND operator `&&` has higher precedence than the logical OR operator `||`, so this is equivalent to:

```
if ((question == compare_question && answer == compare_answer) ||
    answer == compareAnswerChoice)
```

What you probably want is this:

```
if (question == compare_question &&
       (answer == compare_answer || answer == compareAnswerChoice))
```

Comment: The former is what I'd like; the values for answer and compareAnswerChoice are indeed equal, but it still doesn't not run properly. I'll edit in more code to show what happens before the if statement.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest you actually create the temporary variables as I've shown, and print their values so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem lies in the fact that `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`. Try adding parens your if statement like

```
if(seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].question==seatingChart[compareRow][compareSeat][compareIncorrectQuestion].question &&
    (seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].answerChoice==seatingChart[compareRow][compareSeat][compareIncorrectQuestion].answerChoice
    || seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].answerChoice==compareAnswerChoice))
```

Comment: I actually want the first two parameters sharing the and operator and the third parameter separate, so I don't think this would fix the problem.

Comment: @user3093536 Would you mind explaining how does the code fail and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: It's the opposite, actually.  The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: The code after the if statement doesn't not execute when seatingChart[row][seat][incorrectQuestion].answerChoice equals compareAnswerChoice. What I'd like for it to be doing is executing when they are equal because of the or operator.

Comment: @user3093536 what do you mean by "it doesn't execute"

Comment: @lizusek I suppose he means it goes directly to `else`.